# $\Pr[X^2=c \cap X=b]=\Pr[\sqrt{c}=b \cap X=b]=?$

Tags: probability

I'm a bit rusty on probability and would like to clarify an issue I have.

In the following example, we end up with a product of two probabilities (please correct me if I'm mistaken in my calculations):
$$\Pr[X^2+Y=c \cap X=b]=\Pr[b^2+Y=c\cap X=b]=\Pr[Y=c-b^2\cap X=b]=$$

now the events are independent (if we assume $Y,X$ are independent) so:

$$=\Pr[Y=c-b^2]\Pr[X=b]$$

and these two terms are well-defined.

**But in the following example,**

$$\Pr[X^2=c \cap X=b]=\Pr[\sqrt{c}=b \cap X=b]=?$$

First, my problem is we have an intersection of a boolean statement and a set. That seems wrong to me.
Second, intuitively, the answer should be $0$ if the statement $\sqrt{c}=b$ is false and $\Pr[X=b]$ if it's true. Assuming this is correct, how can I see this formally? (If it is incorrect, what is the right approach?)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks - how can the second equality be justified formally? i.e. the $P[b^2=c\land X=b]=..$ part. It also seems that we moved from an intersection of events to a conjunction of boolean statement where one of them is a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and using the comment by @SassatelliGiulio I think the solution lies in the formal definition that goes back to the space of events as such:

$$ \Pr[X^2=c \cap X=b]= \Pr\big[\{ \omega \in \Omega \mid X^2(\omega)=c \wedge X(\omega)=b\}\big] =\Pr\big[\{ \omega \in \Omega \mid b^2=c \wedge X(\omega)=b\}\big]=
\begin{cases}\Pr\big[\{ \omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega)=b\}\big]=\Pr[X=b]&\text{if }b^2=c\\ \Pr[\emptyset]=0&\text{if }b^2\ne c\end{cases}$$